# Loadrunner 11.52 Chrome compatibility

Tags: google-chrome, loadrunner

What versions of chrome are compatible with loadrunner 11.52 on windows?
I saw a post that said version 26 was supported, but Im looking to record using chrome version 13 on windows 7 
NB: Browser version is mandated by the project. 
NNB: Assume playback is browser agnostic - as the commands generated will send the raw HTTP(S) requests to the target server, without any UI

Comment: I think version 13 should be ok, if you experience any problems post them here and I will check.

Comment: Thanks. I considered using 'web - click&script, but I have correlation to do & Ajax & JSon to contend with. So far I have been able to record with IE - But that might change the deeper In I get. Everyone says the browser doesn't matter for playback, but You still send a user-agent string that identifies the browser - So its not agnostic I thought about using Browser emulation for playback, but the version of chrome I need isn't listed - Coul I edit the user-agent string in default.cfg?

Comment: You can edit the user agent in the runtime-settings to any string you like. I still think you should be able to record with Chrome with no issues. Did you try it?

Comment: Yep. I tried recording 7 or 8 times using chrome. I get constant hangs and timeouts. I don't experience the same delays when I use chrome outside of loadrunner to perform the same actions. Loadrunner has been fine with IE - Just supper slow with Chrome (8 minutes to return gooogle.com). I noticed chrome starts in incognito mode - can I change that ?

Comment: Nb: I read some other comments about using chrome, and I make sure there are no other instances of chrome running when I start recording by looking for and killing all chrome instances in task manager

Comment: I just recorded again , and quit before I got the site up (so recorded for about 4 minutes with an empty chrome screen and a spinning timer) to see what Loadrunner recorded - I got web_url, web_add_cookie & web_custom_request for google safebrowsing & related api - Could this be causing the delay ?

Comment: How do I pass command line arguments to chrome when I start recording eg: --chrome-version and --user-data-dir, I don't seem to be able to do it in the recording options ?

Comment: I just tried recording Chrome as a windows application. It opens it in regular mode but didn't record anything. Could you open a support ticket or send exactly what you are doing to LoadRunner feedback (in VuGen help menu). You can try using Proxy recording as James Pulley suggested.

Comment: in Start Recording dialog select Windows Application (instead of browser) then set the path to chrome.exe and pass any arguments you want.

Comment: But why does chrome start in incognito ? I've seen this mentioned elsewhere, but I've not seen a solution ?

Comment: I asked the QA responsible for this feature and the answer is that we start incognito mode to avoid cache hits. In incognito mode we can be sure that all the traffic will go out to the server correctly. During replay we DO simulate cache if needed.

Answer (score 0):

All versions when using the proxy recording model.

Answer (score 0):

> I just recorded again , and quit before I got the site up (so recorded for about 4 minutes with an empty chrome screen and a spinning timer) to see what Loadrunner recorded - I got web_url, web_add_cookie & web_custom_request for google safebrowsing & related api - ...

Unless you work for Google or have their expressed written permission then you do not use automated tools against their site.   This is why the sample applications exist.   Or, you may download and install onto a server you own, control, manage, ... any of the thousands of open source applications which are available on the market.

Pointing an automated tool at a site you don't own, manage or control is no different than driving down the street and shooting at parked cars, homes and signs just because they are there and you can.   Pointing a performance testing tool at the same is akin to pointing a piece of field artillery at someone's home.  This is something you do not engage in as a performance test professional.

Comment: As far as I know Chrome sends some data to Google no matter what you do. So any time you try to record Chrome you will get some calls to Google's APIs. It is up to you to remove them. Privacy FTW.